# Matplotlib - Assign specific colors to a surface

Tags: python, matplotlib

This snippet of code is going to generate the following two pictures, which represents a complex function. Is it possible to apply the colors of the first image to the surface? If so, how?

[image: domain coloring]

[image: 3d magnitude]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb

def saw_func(x, dx, a, b):
    x = x / dx - np.floor(x / dx)
    return a + (b - a) * x

def domain_coloring(mag, arg, phaseres=20):
    arg[arg < 0] += 2 * np.pi
    arg /= (2 * np.pi)
    blackp = saw_func(arg, 1 / phaseres, 0.75, 1)
    blackm = saw_func(np.log(mag), 2 * np.pi / phaseres, 0.75, 1)
    black = blackp * blackm
    H = arg
    S, V = np.ones_like(H), black
    return (hsv_to_rgb(np.dstack([H, S, V])) * 255).astype(np.uint8)

x = y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 500)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = x + 1j * y
f = (z - 1) / (z**2 + z + 1)
mag, arg = np.absolute(f), np.angle(f)
img = domain_coloring(mag, arg)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.imshow(
    img,
    extent = [np.amin(x), np.amax(x), np.amin(y), np.amax(y)], 
    interpolation = "nearest",
    origin = "lower",
)
plt.show()

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")
ax2.plot_surface(x, y, mag)
ax2.set_zlim([0, 10])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/custom_shaded_3d_surface.html) uses a parameter `facecolors=`. The colors need to be rgb values between 0 and 1. The example code uses a 200x200 grid, as 500x500 is rather slow (and also has more problems with artifacts at the asymptotes). `rstride` and `cstride` are set to `1` as default `plot_surface` skips points.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb

def saw_func(x, dx, a, b):
    x = x / dx - np.floor(x / dx)
    return a + (b - a) * x

def domain_coloring(mag, arg, phaseres=20):
    arg[arg < 0] += 2 * np.pi
    arg /= (2 * np.pi)
    blackp = saw_func(arg, 1 / phaseres, 0.75, 1)
    blackm = saw_func(np.log(mag), 2 * np.pi / phaseres, 0.75, 1)
    black = blackp * blackm
    H = arg
    S, V = np.ones_like(H), black
    return hsv_to_rgb(np.dstack([H, S, V]))

x = y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 200)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = x + 1j * y
f = (z - 1) / (z**2 + z + 1)
mag, arg = np.absolute(f), np.angle(f)
img = domain_coloring(mag, arg)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")
ax2.plot_surface(x, y, mag, facecolors=img)
ax2.set_zlim([0, 10])
plt.show()
```

[image: plot_surface with facecolors]